# Android BLE not showing results

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to scan for BLE devices around me. All i am getting is error code 2 and in some other occasions 'onBatchScanResults' returns empty list indefinitely. I am using redmi note 4 device. Thanks in advance.

My code :

```
    BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    final BluetoothLeScanner scanner = adapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();


    final ScanSettings scanSettings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
            .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER)
            .setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES)
            .setMatchMode(ScanSettings.MATCH_MODE_STICKY)
            .setNumOfMatches(ScanSettings.MATCH_NUM_MAX_ADVERTISEMENT)
            .setReportDelay(1000L)
            //.setLegacy(true)
            .build();

   btn_Scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onClick:   ");
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (scanner != null) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "scanner:   ");
                        scanner.startScan(null, scanSettings, new ScanCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
                                super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
                                Log.e(TAG, "onScanResult:   " + result);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
                                super.onBatchScanResults(results);
                                Log.e(TAG, "onBatchScanResults:     " + results);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
                                super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
                                Log.e(TAG, "onScanFailed:   ###    " + errorCode);
                            }
                        });

                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "could not get scanner object");
                    }
                }
            });
            thread.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you enabled GPS on your phone and in the app manifest? You need to actively ask  for location permission to use BLE.

Comment: Maybe you need to increase the scan time also? I use .setReportDelay(10000)

Comment: OK, I will try it. Thanks